# Does LAMP Stack have a GUI?

Tags: centos, gui, apache-httpd

I just bought a VPS server with LAMP. I have SSH access, however no clue how to use LAMP.

I used to work with cPanel in the past. So far, when I type the server address I get the default "Apache 2 Test Page".

I wonder if LAMP has some sort of GUI control panel? If so what would be the way to install and access it on CentOS 6?

Comment: You can use the phpmyadmin interface: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest

Comment: phpmyadmin only allows management of databases.

Answer (score 1):

no, the LAMP-stack does not have a GUI.

*LAMP* is an acronym for:

- Linux: the OS-kernel

  - usually there is no GUI for administering the kernel of your system
- Apache: a web-server

  - simply put: no, afaik there is no GUI to administer apache
- MySQL

  - there's `phpmyadmin` to administer this service, but it requires `apache` and `php` to be configured correctly
- PHP

  - simply put: no, afaik there is no GUI to administer apache/php

most administrative *GUIs* for administering *servers* are web-based GUIs: this means that you need to have a web-service running (apache), with programming capabilities (php), both running on the system (linux). you obviously have to have these systems up and running in order to build upon them.

to conclude: *LAMP* is about *server* administration. *servers* in unix-world usually do not have without a nice GUI to configure everything. instead the user is supposed to configure their system on from the cmdline.

the best you can get to get you started, is probably a book on LAMP, to learn the basics (check [o'reilly](http://oreilly.com)).

Answer (score 1):

The software you're looking for is called [XAMPP for Linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html). There are several release of this software for Windows and OSX too.

#### Installation

1. Download XAMPP - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html
2. Make the download executable

   ```
   $ sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run
   $ sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run
   ```
3. Start XAMPP

   ```
   $ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
   ```
4. Test the install, accessing it via `http://localhost`.

   If it worked you should see a screen like this.

   [image: ss of xampp test]
5. To see more of XAMPP in action you can take a look at the screenshots section of their website. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux-screenshots.html

#### Examples

[image: status page of services]

It also includes several demos and it also comes with PHPMyAdmin for managing MySQL databases!

#### But wait there's more!

XAMPP doesn't just give you a LAMP stack, it's actually a platform from which you can install other web stacks on top of it. These [addons are available from the BitNami for XAMPP website](http://bitnami.com/stack/xampp).

Here's a list of the addons:

- WordPress
- Joomla!
- CMS Made Simple
- Drupal
- MediaWiki
- PrestaShop
- Moodle
- ownCloud
- SugarCRM
- Magento
- Zurmo
- TestLink
- DokuWiki
- Osclass
- phpBB

The addon "stacks" can be downloaded and installed fairly easily from the BitNami website.

[image: ss of downloads]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you learn to use the command-line interface, as that will be useful to you in the future. GUIs differ, but most CLI programs remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel is a GUI interface for LAMP stack, but its paid. Webmin, ISPConfig, Zpanel is a good alternative for it (free version). All you need to do is to configure them according to your needs. They have modules to provide you GUI interface for easy access.

But as in case of Cpanel too all basic configuration needs to be done through commandline first and after installing appropriate mudule for them you can manage them through GUI with any of the tool I mentioned above.

Comment: If what you posted was a quote, you should use `>` in order to quote it, and you should provide a citation.

Comment: You're welcome. But again, if this is a quote, you should provide a link to the source.

Answer (score -1):

webmin may help you with this. There is no "GUI" specifically made for the LAMP stack, but with webmin you can install modules for a web based interface to manage Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

Answer (score -2):

Posting my comment as an answer as I think it is such:

You can use the phpmyadmin [interface](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest).

Comment: I know PhpMyAdmin its just for MySQL, i meant general interface to link several domains to server, setup ftp access, etc.